# Datetime value different from timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I do not understand why the timestamp  at `$start1` is `1661374800 - 24/08/2022 23:00:00` when `$start` value is `2022-08-24 21:00:00.000000`

```
    $timezone = wp_timezone();
    $currentTime = wp_date( 'U', time(), $timezone ); // 1661355604 - 24/08/2022 17:40:04

    $start = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'G:i', '21:00'); // $start->date = 2022-08-24 21:00:00.000000
    $start1 = $start->getTimestamp(); // 1661374800 - 24/08/2022 23:00:00
    $startTime = wp_date( 'U', strtotime( '21:00'), $timezone ); // 1661374800 - 24/08/2022 23:00:00
```

`$timezone` value :

```
DateTimeZone Object
(
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Paris
)
```

What I need is a timestamp for `21h00` each day.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Calling `getTimestamp()` would give you the timestamp as UTC, so I'm guessing that's the first disconnect. Additionally, the `strtotime` function has a [warning in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php): _The Unix timestamp that this function returns does not contain information about time zones_ so you might have potential problems there, too.

Comment: Notice how all the `wp_` functions take the timezone as an argument? Perhaps `createFromFormat()` could as well.

Comment: @Sammitch WordPress is getting the timezone in their option and then use DateTimeZone() https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.0/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L118-L148

Comment: So there's no way to have a localized timestamp? It's allways the UTC timestamp ?

Comment: 1. Look at the third parameter of [`createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat). 2. No. Timestamps are _always_ UTC because it is simply not possible to encode a timezone into a simple integer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the server's timezone is different from your WP timezone. You can check that with:

```
var_dump(date_default_timezone_get());
```

The solution is to use your $timezone as the third parameter of `createFromFormat()`.

```
$timezone = wp_timezone();
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'G:i', '21:00', $timezone);

//test
echo date_create('Now',$timezone)
  ->setTimeStamp($start1)
  ->format('d.m.Y H:i');
```